# Return a value from custom (modal) alert box

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Please find the below code...

```
var res = confirm("Are you Sure?");
alert(res);
```

In the above confirm box When you click the 'OK', you will get the returned value of 'true', and 'false' for clicking the 'CANCEL'. How do we return a value (0 or 1) from jquery custom modal box plugin, like above confirm box?

Find the following fiddle for sample and plug-in script in http://jsfiddle.net/yesvin/N2Qu7/

**Complete HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Custom Modal</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>      
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .btnCls, .btnCls:hover {
                border-radius: 10px;
                background: #cff73d; 
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f0ffc3 0%, #cff73d 100%); 
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f0ffc3), color-stop(100%,#cff73d)); 
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f0ffc3 0%,#cff73d 100%); 
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f0ffc3 0%,#cff73d 100%); 
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f0ffc3 0%,#cff73d 100%); 
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0ffc3 0%,#cff73d 100%); 
                filter: progid :DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0ffc3', endColorstr='#cff73d',GradientType=0 ); 
                border: 1px solid #364b4d;
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #536803 !important;
            }

            #modOverlay {
                position:fixed; 
                top:0;
                left:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background:#000;
                opacity:0.7;
                filter:alpha(opacity=70);
                z-index:1000;
            }

            #modalWin {
                position:absolute;              
                background:#D8DBB6;             
                border:none;
                border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
                padding:15px;
                z-index:1000;
            }

            #modContent {
                border-radius:8px;
                /*background:#fff;*/
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
                height:auto;
                width:220px;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 12px;                
            }

            #modContent h3{
                 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #69820B;
                border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-size: 16px;
                left: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px 5px 10px 15px;
                position: absolute;
                top: -36px;
                width: 240px;

            }

            #modContent p{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 0 0 0px;
            }

            button {
                border:solid 1px #565656;
                margin: 8px 7px 0 0;
                cursor:pointer;
                font-size:12px;
                padding:5px;
                border:none;
                border-radius:5px!important;    
            }

            #clsBtn {               
                position:absolute;
                top:-40px;
                right:-3px;
            }

            .icon{
                 display: block;
                height: 24px;
                left: 15px;
                position: absolute;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                top: 20px;
                width: 24px;
            }
        </style> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var customModal = (function(){
                var  
                method = {},
                returnValue,
                $overlay,
                $content,
                $title,
                $message,
                $close, 

                $buttonMode,
                $ok,    
                $cancel,

                $okFunc,
                $cancelFunc,

                $icon,
                $status,        

                $modal;         

                $overlay = $('<div id="modOverlay"></div>');
                $modal = $('<div id="modalWin" class="ui-body-c"></div>');
                $title = $('<h3></h3>')
                $message = $('<p></p>') 
                $content = $('<div id="modContent"></div>');
                $close = $('<button id="clsBtn" class="btnCls">X</button>');
                $icon = $('<div class="icon"></div>')

                $ok = $('<button id="ok" class="btnCls">OK</button>')
                $cancel = $('<button id="cancel" class="btnCls">Cancel</button>')

                $content.append($title, $message, $icon);   

                $modal.hide();
                $overlay.hide();

                method.center = function () {
                    var top, left;

                    top = Math.max($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;
                    left = Math.max($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;

                    $modal.css({
                        top:top + $(window).scrollTop(), 
                        left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
                    });
                };

                method.open = function (settings) {
                    $title.empty().append(settings.title);
                    $message.empty().append(settings.message);
                    $status = settings.status;
                    retValue = settings.returnValue;

                    switch(settings.status)
                    {
                        case 'Warning':
                        $icon.removeClass('infoIcn');
                        $icon.removeClass('succeesIcn');
                        $icon.removeClass('errorIcn');
                        $icon.addClass('waringIcn');            
                        break;
                        case 'Success':
                        $icon.removeClass('infoIcn');           
                        $icon.removeClass('errorIcn');
                        $icon.removeClass('waringIcn');
                        $icon.addClass('succeesIcn');
                        break;
                        case 'Error':
                        $icon.removeClass('infoIcn');
                        $icon.removeClass('succeesIcn');            
                        $icon.removeClass('waringIcn');
                        $icon.addClass('errorIcn');
                        break;
                        case 'Info':
                        $icon.removeClass('succeesIcn');            
                        $icon.removeClass('waringIcn');
                        $icon.removeClass('errorIcn');
                        $icon.addClass('infoIcn');
                        break;  
                    }   

                    switch(settings.buttonMode)
                    {
                    case 'ok':        
                      $modal.append($content, $close, $ok);                                       
                      break;
                    case 'cancel':        
                      $modal.append($content, $close, $cancel);   
                      break;
                    case 'both':
                      $modal.append($content, $close, $ok, $cancel);         
                      break; 
                    default:
                      $modal.append($content, $close, $ok, $cancel);          
                    }       

                    $modal.css({
                        width: settings.width || 'auto', 
                        height: settings.height || 'auto'           
                    });

                    method.center();
                    $modal.show();
                    $overlay.show();
                };

                method.close = function () {
                    $modal.hide();
                    $overlay.hide();
                    $title.empty();
                    $message.empty();       
                };

                method.retrnFunc = function (i) {
                    retValue = i;       
                    alert(retValue);            
                };  

                $close.click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    method.close();
                });

                $ok.click(function(e){          
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    method.retrnFunc(0);                
                });

                $cancel.click(function(e){          
                    e.preventDefault();     
                    method.retrnFunc(1);                        
                });

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('body').append($overlay, $modal);                     
                });

                return method;
            }());

            $(function (){              
                $("#btn").click(function (){
                    var result = customModal.open({title: "Confirmation", message:"Are you sure?",buttonMode:"both"});
                    alert(result);
                });

                if (result){
                    //do something if true
                }
                else {
                    //do something if false
                }

            });             

        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>      
        <button id="btn">Open Confirm?</button>​
    </body>
</html>
```

Advice me how do we return a value (0 or 1) from jquery custom modal box plugin, like above confirm box?

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Always put **all** of the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link (not even to jsFiddle). Naturally, before doing that, you want to make sure what you're posting is the [**minimum necessary**](http://sscce.org). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: All the relevant code has been placed...

Comment: @ Yesvinkumar: About that [**minimum necessary**](http://sscce.org/) part...

Comment: Tell me where did you find that implementation of modal window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop the JavaScript thread the way `confirm` does, but you don't need to:

Make one of the settings you pass into `open` a callback function, and call that function with an argument telling it what button was pressed (or whatever else it needs to tell it).

In your code, it looks like you reuse one set of variables for your modal, so you'd add `callback` to your big `var` and assign to it from the settings object in `open`. Then in `close`, call that function and clear the variable.

So in the big `var`:

```
// ...
$status,
$modal,
$callback; // <== The new bit
```

And in `open`:

```
// ...
retValue = settings.returnValue;
$callback = settings.callback;   // <== The new bit
```

And in `retrnFunc`:

```
if ($callback) {
    try {
        $callback(i);
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    $callback = undefined;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
customModal.open({
    // ...other settings...
    callback: function(i) {
        alert(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, your custom modal does not block in the same way that the default `confirm` popup does.  So, you can't just have your code immediately return a result.  One option would be to pass a callback function as a parameter to `open`.  Then you could call it like this:

```
customModal.open(
    {
        title: "Confirmation", 
        message:"Are you sure?",
        buttonMode:"both"
    }, 
    function(result){
       alert("RESULT FROM CALLBACK: " + result);
    }
);
```

Alternatively, you could also include the callback in your option object you pass instead of as a separate parameter.

Then in your `open` function, simply replace your default result function with the passed callback:

```
method.open = function (settings, callback) {
    /* ... */

    method.retrnFunc = callback;
```

This has to be treated in much the same way as an asynchronous call, as you have to wait for user interaction before you can process the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/N2Qu7/5/

Answer (score -1):

In simple words, and using tertiary operator:

```
var res = (confirm("Are you Sure?"))? 1:0;
alert(res);
```

Comment: OP wants to use custom modal box plugin as i can read the question